# How do I convert .tsl video files from my Philips TV to a more common file format?

Tags: tv, video-conversion, avi

I have a Philips 6606H TV, which can record files onto my external hard drive via USB. The files are recorded into a .tsl file, which I have now copied to my Windows 7 PC hard drive.

Now, I want to open and convert the file, but I can't find any software that can open or convert the file into a format like .avi.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you play those files with VLC? Have you tried [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverterDown.htm) ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but nothing happened. But as you can see beneath, there's really not much for VLC to do with it, as it is encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in an [announcement](http://www.supportforum.philips.com/en/showthread.php?1914-USB-Recording-your-experiences) on the Philips forums about being able to record they mentioned:

> Saved Recordings will be encrypted and can only be decrypted with the same TV, so sharing movies will NOT be possible.

Comment: Man, that sucks. Thanks for the answer and the source though. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a little problem with TV's that can record in their own format, they are read by the same TV only.

I tried once when I recorded with my TV, nothing could read it.

No converters able to recognize it, nothing, only my tv was able to see them.

So, if you still need to save them, you should record those pieces with another recorder, A cam maybe?

Answer (score -1):

[KMPlayer](http://www.kmpmedia.net/) can play .tsl files. You can somehow recode it via [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)

Comment: Might be worth going into more detail on how this could be achieved.

Comment: Some more details would be nice. I am not able to open .tsl-files in KMPlayer. I get a warning popup with a dump of the file and some information on my computer.

Comment: "Somehow"? Come on, that kind of vague reply is the same as nothing.